# How do I create a temporary DataMapper model for RSpec testing?

Tags: ruby, rspec, datamapper

I'd like to create a DataMapper model just for the duration of an RSpec test, along these lines.  But how do I create the underlying temp_models table from within the RSpec test?

```
require 'spec_helper'

class TempModel
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :foo, String
end

describe "MyTests" do
  before(:all) do
    # what goes here to create the table and finalize the model?
  end
  after(:all) do
    # what goes here to drop the table?
  end
  before(:each) do
    TempModel.destroy!
  end

  it 'creates a TempModel' do
    expect { TempModel.create(:foo => "yowza")}.to_not raise_error
  end
end
```

So, like the code says, what do I put in the `before(:all)` block to create the table in the db and create the DataMapper model?  And in the `after(:all)` block to drop the table?

### update

Alternatively, how can I create a "local migration" and perform the up and down on it?

Comment: FWIW, I tried adding `DataMapper.finalize ; DataMapper.auto_migrate!` in the `before(:all)` block, but that causes entirely unrelated tests to break with `DataObjects::IntegrityError` foreign key constraint errors.

Comment: Not quite sure I'm understanding your question. Is `dm-is-reflective` (https://github.com/godfat/dm-is-reflective) what you're looking for? It allows you to mirror your database so you can do datamapper commands on it.

Comment: @AlexQueue: Sorry if the question wasn't clear -- I'll update the question.  The dm-is-reflective gem won't help because it "creates mappings between existing columns" and those columns don't exist until the table is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug around the sources and experimented to come up with this solution.  If anyone has improvements on this, please let me know:

```
require 'spec_helper'

class TempModel
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :foo, String
end

describe "MyTests" do
  before(:all) do
    DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
    TempModel.finalize
  end
  after(:all) do
    adapter = DataMapper.repository(:default).adapter
    adapter.execute("DROP TABLE #{TempModel.storage_name}")
  end
  before(:each) do
    TempModel.destroy!
  end

  it 'creates a TempModel' do
    expect { TempModel.create(:foo => "yowza")}.to_not raise_error
  end
end
```